# What's the official term, or noun phrase, for "the last date at which a book states or reflects the law"?

Tags: legal-terms

I've seen  this noun phrase in older judgments, but it slipped my mind. What's the official pithy term for this date? **In other words, how can you briefly describe this date in this format ― the (last) date of + FILL IN THE BLANKS?** I would guess "the last date of substantive law coverage", but Googling this proves that this isn't the official term! The [Civil Procedure Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Procedure_Rules#The_overriding_objective) might have obsoleted this term as "archaic" legalese.

Below are examples of this date in law textbooks.

> This seventh edition aims to state the law as it stood on 1 May 2015 when the manuscript was complete, although it has been possible to incorporate certain later developments at
> the proof stage.

Stelios Tofaris, *Hepple and Matthews' Tort Law* (7 edn, 2015, Hart Publishing Ltd), Preface on page viii.

> We have attempted to state the law as at 4th August 2021, though we were able to insert
> a few additions late on in the editing stage.

Antonia Layard, *Thompson's Modern Land Law* (8 edn, 2022, OUP), Preface on page v. The Preface doesn't print the page number, but I counted backwards from the first page that printed Roman numerals.

> This edition purports to state the law as it was on 30 November 2018, but it has been possible to incorporate
> some more recent developments where space has permitted.

Graham Virgo and Paul Davies, *Equity & Trusts Text, Cases, and Materials* (3 edn, 2019, OUP), Preface on page vi.

Comment: If the word exists, don’t you think these books would have used it?

Comment: "Current though" or "coverage though"?

Comment: @DaleM These books were recently published, way after the CPR. And I edited my post. ["The CPR were designed to improve access to justice by making legal proceedings cheaper, quicker, and easier to understand for non-lawyers. As a consequence of this, many archaic legal terms were replaced with "plain English" equivalents, such as "claimant" for "plaintiff" and "witness summons" for "subpoena". "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Procedure_Rules)